# Stocks widget on mac os mojave not showing current prices

Tags: mojave, dashboard-widget

About a weeks back, the stocks widget on mac os mojave stopped showing the current prices.

[image]

Does anyone know of a workaround to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: It ends up making a call to http://api.apple.go.yahoo.com/dgw which is not up any more.

Answer (score 2):

The Stocks widget gets its data from Yahoo:

```
$ cd /Library/Widgets/Stocks.wdgt
$ grep http Stocks.*
Stocks.html:    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
Stocks.js:              var url = 'http://api.apple.go.yahoo.com/appledwf/q?s=' + symbol;
Stocks.js:      openLink('http://api.apple.go.yahoo.com/appledwf/');
Stocks.js:      var url = "http://api.apple.go.yahoo.com/appledwf/q/cq?d=v1";
```

The server used seems to be offline though

```
$ ping api.apple.go.yahoo.com
ping: cannot resolve api.apple.go.yahoo.com: Unknown host
```

most probably Yahoo changed the API. I also found pages mentioning that the API got deprecated by Yahoo already years ago. Combining this with the fact that Apple deprecated Dashboard as well you may want to use other ways to access that data.